# how to fix the size of multiline edit text

Tags: android

I want to make a multi line edit text but the problem is that whenever i enter new line height of edit text increases. how to fix its height. My code is

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editAdditionalInfo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editPhoneCutomerDetails"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editPhoneCutomerDetails"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/message_additional_box1x"
    android:ems="10"  
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:gravity="top">
    <requestFocus />
</EditText>
```

Comment: use android:singleLine="true";

Comment: but i want to make it multi line.

Comment: @Fattie this question already have answer. can you explain more?

Comment: hi @PhanVanLinh, nothing to explain, it is normal to add Bounty to "reward" and other reasons.  on another question, click on "Bounty" and you will see the options.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

To fix the size of editText you can use

```
android:singleLine="true"
```

but it can limit your editText line to 1 .

if you want more lines in editText then use the following property.

Use `android:lines="3"` .

Comment: i want all the texts entered in that edit text to be scrolled vertically.

Comment: @Avinash use android:lines property

Answer (score 12):

Use `android:lines="2"` for fixing **multilines** and **for fixing single line** use `android:singleLine="true"`

for example use like this as shown for **multilines**

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/.."
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background_normal"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Name"
    android:maxLength="20"
    android:lines="2"// fix the multiline limit 
    android:textColor="#000000" />
```

for example use like this as shown for **single line**

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/.."
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background_normal"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Name"
    android:maxLength="20"
    android:singleLine="true"// fix the single line limit 
    android:textColor="#000000" />
```

Answer (score 5):

try this;

> android:inputType="textMultiLine"

```
 <EditText
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Answer (score 4):

As singleline is now deprecated use inputType:multiline and set the number of lines you want with lines tag

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:lines="4"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar requirement but ended up not changing the size of the box. i.e it grows as text is typed into it but stops short of blocking the other widgets in view. I read this post during my quest and had found a solution. Decided to post it back here. Restricting size to a value may possibly have different effects on different screens. So I think it is better to let it be.

The thing is to put the edit text inside a linearlayout with the rest of the widgets. The code and snapshot are here
[Multi line edit box with ok cancel buttons](http://harisankar-krishnaswamy.blogspot.in/2013/07/android-ui-scrollable-edit-text-with-ok.html)